# SVG text animated landing page not working in vscode

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, new-operator

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to do this to do line text svg animation. I followed the steps and tried to creat the file in figma and then create it in vscode. The word pops up but it doesn't animate and I've been searching to no avail on the why?
Can someone help me figure this out? I just want it to go from one end to the other.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>


  <title>Document</title>

  <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa">
</head>

<body>
  <svg 
    width="843" 
    height="118" 
    viewBox="0 0 843 118" 
    fill="forward" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    id="Kink In Kolor"

    <mask id="Kink In Kolor path-1-outside-1" 
    maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
    x="0.0880127" 
    y="0.415993" 
    width="843" 
    height="117"
    fill="black">
      <rect fill="white" x="0.0880127" y="0.415993" width="843" height="117" />
      <path
        d="M57.52 113L16.192 67.208V113H3.08801V12.632H16.192V59.144L57.664 12.632H74.224L28.72 62.888L74.656 113H57.52Z" />
      <path
        d="M96.0591 21.272C93.5631 21.272 91.4511 20.408 89.7231 18.68C87.9951 16.952 87.1311 14.84 87.1311 12.344C87.1311 9.84799 87.9951 7.736 89.7231 6.008C91.4511 4.27999 93.5631 3.41599 96.0591 3.41599C98.4591 3.41599 100.475 4.27999 102.107 6.008C103.835 7.736 104.699 9.84799 104.699 12.344C104.699 14.84 103.835 16.952 102.107 18.68C100.475 20.408 98.4591 21.272 96.0591 21.272ZM102.395 34.088V113H89.2911V34.088H102.395Z" />
      <path
        d="M163.177 32.648C172.777 32.648 180.553 35.576 186.505 41.432C192.457 47.192 195.433 55.544 195.433 66.488V113H182.473V68.36C182.473 60.488 180.505 54.488 176.569 50.36C172.633 46.136 167.257 44.024 160.441 44.024C153.529 44.024 148.009 46.184 143.881 50.504C139.849 54.824 137.833 61.112 137.833 69.368V113H124.729V34.088H137.833V45.32C140.425 41.288 143.929 38.168 148.345 35.96C152.857 33.752 157.801 32.648 163.177 32.648Z" />
      <path
        d="M260.902 113L229.942 78.152V113H216.838V6.44H229.942V69.08L260.326 34.088H278.614L241.462 73.4L278.758 113H260.902Z" />
      <path d="M342.442 12.632V113H329.338V12.632H342.442Z" />
      <path
        d="M403.224 32.648C412.824 32.648 420.6 35.576 426.552 41.432C432.504 47.192 435.479 55.544 435.479 66.488V113H422.52V68.36C422.52 60.488 420.552 54.488 416.616 50.36C412.68 46.136 407.303 44.024 400.487 44.024C393.575 44.024 388.055 46.184 383.927 50.504C379.895 54.824 377.88 61.112 377.88 69.368V113H364.776V34.088H377.88V45.32C380.472 41.288 383.976 38.168 388.392 35.96C392.904 33.752 397.848 32.648 403.224 32.648Z" />
      <path
        d="M549.708 113L508.38 67.208V113H495.276V12.632H508.38V59.144L549.852 12.632H566.411L520.908 62.888L566.844 113H549.708Z" />
      <path
        d="M615.895 114.296C608.503 114.296 601.783 112.616 595.735 109.256C589.783 105.896 585.079 101.144 581.623 95C578.263 88.76 576.583 81.56 576.583 73.4C576.583 65.336 578.311 58.232 581.767 52.088C585.319 45.848 590.119 41.096 596.167 37.832C602.215 34.472 608.983 32.792 616.471 32.792C623.959 32.792 630.727 34.472 636.775 37.832C642.823 41.096 647.575 45.8 651.031 51.944C654.583 58.088 656.359 65.24 656.359 73.4C656.359 81.56 654.535 88.76 650.887 95C647.335 101.144 642.487 105.896 636.343 109.256C630.199 112.616 623.383 114.296 615.895 114.296ZM615.895 102.776C620.599 102.776 625.015 101.672 629.143 99.464C633.271 97.256 636.583 93.944 639.079 89.528C641.671 85.112 642.967 79.736 642.967 73.4C642.967 67.064 641.719 61.688 639.223 57.272C636.727 52.856 633.463 49.592 629.431 47.48C625.399 45.272 621.031 44.168 616.327 44.168C611.527 44.168 607.111 45.272 603.079 47.48C599.143 49.592 595.975 52.856 593.575 57.272C591.175 61.688 589.975 67.064 589.975 73.4C589.975 79.832 591.127 85.256 593.431 89.672C595.831 94.088 598.999 97.4 602.935 99.608C606.871 101.72 611.191 102.776 615.895 102.776Z" />
      <path d="M686.692 6.44V113H673.588V6.44H686.692Z" />
      <path
        d="M743.442 114.296C736.05 114.296 729.329 112.616 723.281 109.256C717.329 105.896 712.625 101.144 709.169 95C705.809 88.76 704.13 81.56 704.13 73.4C704.13 65.336 705.857 58.232 709.313 52.088C712.865 45.848 717.666 41.096 723.714 37.832C729.762 34.472 736.53 32.792 744.018 32.792C751.506 32.792 758.274 34.472 764.322 37.832C770.37 41.096 775.122 45.8 778.578 51.944C782.13 58.088 783.906 65.24 783.906 73.4C783.906 81.56 782.081 88.76 778.433 95C774.881 101.144 770.034 105.896 763.89 109.256C757.746 112.616 750.93 114.296 743.442 114.296ZM743.442 102.776C748.146 102.776 752.562 101.672 756.69 99.464C760.818 97.256 764.129 93.944 766.625 89.528C769.217 85.112 770.513 79.736 770.513 73.4C770.513 67.064 769.266 61.688 766.77 57.272C764.274 52.856 761.009 49.592 756.977 47.48C752.945 45.272 748.577 44.168 743.873 44.168C739.073 44.168 734.657 45.272 730.625 47.48C726.689 49.592 723.522 52.856 721.122 57.272C718.722 61.688 717.521 67.064 717.521 73.4C717.521 79.832 718.673 85.256 720.977 89.672C723.377 94.088 726.546 97.4 730.482 99.608C734.418 101.72 738.738 102.776 743.442 102.776Z" />
      <path
        d="M814.239 46.904C816.543 42.392 819.807 38.888 824.031 36.392C828.351 33.896 833.583 32.648 839.727 32.648V46.184H836.271C821.583 46.184 814.239 54.152 814.239 70.088V113H801.135V34.088H814.239V46.904Z" />
    </mask>
    <path
      d="M57.52 113L16.192 67.208V113H3.08801V12.632H16.192V59.144L57.664 12.632H74.224L28.72 62.888L74.656 113H57.52Z"
      stroke="#A12DCA" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)" />
    <path
      d="M96.0591 21.272C93.5631 21.272 91.4511 20.408 89.7231 18.68C87.9951 16.952 87.1311 14.84 87.1311 12.344C87.1311 9.84799 87.9951 7.736 89.7231 6.008C91.4511 4.27999 93.5631 3.41599 96.0591 3.41599C98.4591 3.41599 100.475 4.27999 102.107 6.008C103.835 7.736 104.699 9.84799 104.699 12.344C104.699 14.84 103.835 16.952 102.107 18.68C100.475 20.408 98.4591 21.272 96.0591 21.272ZM102.395 34.088V113H89.2911V34.088H102.395Z"
      stroke="#A12DCA" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)" />
    <path
      d="M163.177 32.648C172.777 32.648 180.553 35.576 186.505 41.432C192.457 47.192 195.433 55.544 195.433 66.488V113H182.473V68.36C182.473 60.488 180.505 54.488 176.569 50.36C172.633 46.136 167.257 44.024 160.441 44.024C153.529 44.024 148.009 46.184 143.881 50.504C139.849 54.824 137.833 61.112 137.833 69.368V113H124.729V34.088H137.833V45.32C140.425 41.288 143.929 38.168 148.345 35.96C152.857 33.752 157.801 32.648 163.177 32.648Z"
      stroke="#A12DCA" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)" />
    <path
      d="M260.902 113L229.942 78.152V113H216.838V6.44H229.942V69.08L260.326 34.088H278.614L241.462 73.4L278.758 113H260.902Z"
      stroke="#A12DCA" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)" />
    <path d="M342.442 12.632V113H329.338V12.632H342.442Z" stroke="#A12DCA" stroke-width="6"
      mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)" />
    <path
      d="M403.224 32.648C412.824 32.648 420.6 35.576 426.552 41.432C432.504 47.192 435.479 55.544 435.479 66.488V113H422.52V68.36C422.52 60.488 420.552 54.488 416.616 50.36C412.68 46.136 407.303 44.024 400.487 44.024C393.575 44.024 388.055 46.184 383.927 50.504C379.895 54.824 377.88 61.112 377.88 69.368V113H364.776V34.088H377.88V45.32C380.472 41.288 383.976 38.168 388.392 35.96C392.904 33.752 397.848 32.648 403.224 32.648Z"
      stroke="#A12DCA" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)" />
    <path
      d="M549.708 113L508.38 67.208V113H495.276V12.632H508.38V59.144L549.852 12.632H566.411L520.908 62.888L566.844 113H549.708Z"
      stroke="#A12DCA" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)" />
    <path
      d="M615.895 114.296C608.503 114.296 601.783 112.616 595.735 109.256C589.783 105.896 585.079 101.144 581.623 95C578.263 88.76 576.583 81.56 576.583 73.4C576.583 65.336 578.311 58.232 581.767 52.088C585.319 45.848 590.119 41.096 596.167 37.832C602.215 34.472 608.983 32.792 616.471 32.792C623.959 32.792 630.727 34.472 636.775 37.832C642.823 41.096 647.575 45.8 651.031 51.944C654.583 58.088 656.359 65.24 656.359 73.4C656.359 81.56 654.535 88.76 650.887 95C647.335 101.144 642.487 105.896 636.343 109.256C630.199 112.616 623.383 114.296 615.895 114.296ZM615.895 102.776C620.599 102.776 625.015 101.672 629.143 99.464C633.271 97.256 636.583 93.944 639.079 89.528C641.671 85.112 642.967 79.736 642.967 73.4C642.967 67.064 641.719 61.688 639.223 57.272C636.727 52.856 633.463 49.592 629.431 47.48C625.399 45.272 621.031 44.168 616.327 44.168C611.527 44.168 607.111 45.272 603.079 47.48C599.143 49.592 595.975 52.856 593.575 57.272C591.175 61.688 589.975 67.064 589.975 73.4C589.975 79.832 591.127 85.256 593.431 89.672C595.831 94.088 598.999 97.4 602.935 99.608C606.871 101.72 611.191 102.776 615.895 102.776Z"
      stroke="#A12DCA" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)" />
    <path d="M686.692 6.44V113H673.588V6.44H686.692Z" stroke="#A12DCA" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)" />
    <path
      d="M743.442 114.296C736.05 114.296 729.329 112.616 723.281 109.256C717.329 105.896 712.625 101.144 709.169 95C705.809 88.76 704.13 81.56 704.13 73.4C704.13 65.336 705.857 58.232 709.313 52.088C712.865 45.848 717.666 41.096 723.714 37.832C729.762 34.472 736.53 32.792 744.018 32.792C751.506 32.792 758.274 34.472 764.322 37.832C770.37 41.096 775.122 45.8 778.578 51.944C782.13 58.088 783.906 65.24 783.906 73.4C783.906 81.56 782.081 88.76 778.433 95C774.881 101.144 770.034 105.896 763.89 109.256C757.746 112.616 750.93 114.296 743.442 114.296ZM743.442 102.776C748.146 102.776 752.562 101.672 756.69 99.464C760.818 97.256 764.129 93.944 766.625 89.528C769.217 85.112 770.513 79.736 770.513 73.4C770.513 67.064 769.266 61.688 766.77 57.272C764.274 52.856 761.009 49.592 756.977 47.48C752.945 45.272 748.577 44.168 743.873 44.168C739.073 44.168 734.657 45.272 730.625 47.48C726.689 49.592 723.522 52.856 721.122 57.272C718.722 61.688 717.521 67.064 717.521 73.4C717.521 79.832 718.673 85.256 720.977 89.672C723.377 94.088 726.546 97.4 730.482 99.608C734.418 101.72 738.738 102.776 743.442 102.776Z"
      stroke="#A12DCA" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)" />
    <path
      d="M814.239 46.904C816.543 42.392 819.807 38.888 824.031 36.392C828.351 33.896 833.583 32.648 839.727 32.648V46.184H836.271C821.583 46.184 814.239 54.152 814.239 70.088V113H801.135V34.088H814.239V46.904Z"
      stroke="#A12DCA" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)" />
  </svg>
  <script>
      anime({
          targets: "#Kink In Kolor path- 1 - outside - 1",
          strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
          easing: 'easeInOutSine',
          duration: 1500,
          delay: function(el, i) { return i * 250 },
          direction: 'alternate',
          loop: false,
          });
  </script>


  <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
  <p>Hello world! This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>
  



"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  
  <script>
    window.ga = function () { ga.q.push(arguments) }; ga.q = []; ga.l = +new Date;
    ga('create', 'Kinkinkolor.com', 'auto'); ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true); ga('set', 'transport', 'beacon'); ga('send', 'pageview')
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [whitespace in id values is not valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: @RobertLongson How do I fix it? Do I have to add it as a paragraph?Also, thanks for your response!

Comment: you need to change your id values so they don't contain whitespace.